# Before mail sending validate contact from 7

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming, contact-form-7

I want to check address filed have correct address then send email. My code working but i want to execute my code after contact from 7 validation. if my code return true then form will submit and send email otherwise show alert and should not be submit.

```
$('.wpcf7-submit').on('click', function (e) {
    var address = $('input[name="your-address"]').val();
    //e.preventDefault(); 
    if(city !=="") {
        jQuery.post(gs_cf7_url, {data:address, action:'gs_cf7_check_lat_lag'}, function (response){
            if(response=="no") {
                alert('Sorry we couldnt find the location');
            } else {
                //$(".wpcf7-submit").unbind("submit").submit(); 
                //$(".wpcf7-submit").unbind("submit");
            }
        });
    }
});
```

I am looking a hook such as `add_action('wpcf7_before_send_mail', 'save_form');` if there as any javascript hook?

Answer (score 0):

The logic of Contact From 7 is as follows. On Submit click it fires ajax, performs all validation in php code and returns to js internal function $.wpcf7AjaxSuccess = function(data, status, xhr, $form). This function checks data.invalids and if true, shows error message(s).

This means it is too late to perform your checks after Contact Form 7 validation, because when php code accepts all data as valid, it sends email and returns control to $.wpcf7AjaxSuccess.

As a workaround, you can mark address field as required in CF7, monitor .focusout() event on your field (input[name="your-address"]) and clear it if address entered is not valid. On submit click, CF7 will not send the email then and will require your field.

Try to change your code in this way:

```
$('input[name="your-address"]).focusout( function () {
    var address = $('input[name="your-address"]').val();
    //e.preventDefault(); 
    if(city !=="") {
        jQuery.post(gs_cf7_url, {data:address, action:'gs_cf7_check_lat_lag'}, function (response){
            if(response=="no") {
                alert('Sorry we couldnt find the location');
                $('input[name="your-address"]').val('');
            } else {
                //$(".wpcf7-submit").unbind("submit").submit(); 
                //$(".wpcf7-submit").unbind("submit");
            }
        });
    }
});
```

I didn't check it since I don't have other pieces of your code (gs_cf7_check_lat_lag), so please treat it as idea how to make a workaround.

Comment: Thank you @kagg Design.  Yeah the address filed is required but i want check some other validation ?

Comment: Thank you so much for you help.But what i was looked can check by answer